# Copy Dictionary Path Button for any folders or files in OSX

Tags: macos, mac, macbook, path, dictionary

I want to know there is any option to get Full directory path in OSX from right click.In windows i am able to get full path from properties folders.But that is possible in OSX MAC. Right Click of mouse like this.
[image: want to get "Copy Path" option on right click]

Comment: From right click of what? The dictionary itself?

Comment: right click of mouse

Comment: right click of mouse…**where?** As it stands your question makes no sense.

Comment: see updated question

Comment: Your use of the word 'dictionary' still has me totally confused. If you want the path to the file, or to see it in its true location, it's the last 2 options in your menu.

Comment: sorry for 'dictionary' word. it was mistake! And i copy this image  from web.I want option like this last two menu

Comment: This may help: [Copy File Path](http://osxdaily.com/2015/11/05/copy-file-path-name-text-mac-os-x-finder/)